# (Serial.available() > 0) waits for user input

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I'm facing problem with user input in Arduino ide. I would like arduino to periodically check if user generate some input string (arduino checks it every 3 seconds), but even if there is no input after 3 seconds (string order="") arduino waits for user input and when I type something then it exit "checkIncomingOrder" function and wait another 3 seconds. I would be gratefull for any advice. My simple code is below:

```
String order = "";
int timer;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  timer = 0;
}

void loop() {
  if (timer == 3)
  {
    checkIncomingOrder();
  }
  else
  {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("waiting");
    timer++;
  }
}

void checkIncomingOrder() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) { 
    order = Serial.readStringUntil('\n'); 
  }
  if (order == "") {
    return;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Order is: " + order); 
    order = "";
    timer = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: If there are characters available, `readStringUntil()` will be called, but that will not return until a newline is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Serial::Available()` does not block. If there are characters available, `readStringUntil()` will be called, but that will not return until a newline is available - so that is where your blocking on input is likely to be occurring.

The following is perhaps a safer non-blocking solution:

```
void checkIncomingOrder() 
{
    char ch = 0 ;
    while( ch != '\n' && Serial.available() > 0 ) 
    { 
        Serial.readBytes( &ch, 1 ) ; 
        order += ch ;
    }

    if( ch == '\n' ) 
    {
        Serial.println("Order is: " + order) ; 
        order = "" ;
        timer = 0 ;
    }
}
```

It allows you to check for a line of input continuously rather then every three seconds - making the solution more responsive:

```
void loop() 
{
    checkIncomingOrder();
}
```

allowing in turn the `timer` variable to be removed.